# How to find the minimum value of this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, problem-solving, education

I am struggling to find the solution to this problem. If anyone could help to explain how to solve this problem to me, it would be really appreciated.

Let
$$ f(x)=-\sqrt{3}x+(1+\sqrt{3}) $$  $$ g(x)= f(x)+C  $$ When C varies, find the minimumn of the integral $$\int_0^2[g(x)]^2dx$$

Comment: Square g(x) then integrate between 0 and 2. This will give you a quadratic for C. You want the minimum of that quadratic curve.

Comment: @Paul: the solution can be found without squaring, which simplifies the computation.

Comment: @ Yves Daoust: true.

Answer (score 2):

The value of the integral is (bounds dropped for brevity):
$$I(C)=\int(f(x)+C)^2dx=\int(f^2(x)+2Cf(x)+C^2)dx\\=\int f^2(x)dx+2C\int f(x)dx+C^2\int dx.$$

To find the extrema, find the roots of the first derivative with respect to $C$:

$$\frac{dI}{dC}=2\int f(x)dx+2C\int dx=0.$$

Solving this shouldn't be a big deal...

You will also easily check that the second derivative is positive.

Comment: $C = -f(x)^2 / 2f(x)$ ? But the C not integer, and my answers not right

Comment: @Lifeforbetter: your "integrals" are not correct.